# Android - Check if a row within the DB exists

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've created a method where the app checks if a number exists in the DB:

```
    Cursor player = playerDatabase.rawQuery("select * from playerTable where playerNumber ="+number,null);
  try {
      if (player.getCount() >= 0) {
          player.close();
          return true;
      }
      else{
          return false;
      }
  }finally {
      if(player != null){
          player.close();
      }
  }
```

But the problem is, this always returns true? The reason I am using it this way, is from the previous answers on Stack Overflow.
What is the optimal way of being able to check if a search query returns a row/check if this number exits?

Comment: While I don't know the perfect answer for that, I'd in general add a limiting `limit 1` to your query. That way the engine will be able to drop out after the first (potentially only possible) hit rather then iterating over all entries. This might be non-relevant if the column is set to be unique, but you never know. :)

Comment: This is a logical error, You said you just want to check if the number exists but you use greater or equal to zero instead just greater than zero change this `if (player.getCount() >= 0) ` to `if (player.getCount() >0) `

Comment: Can you provide datatype definitions of DB and the code of "player.getCount()" method.

Comment: @Xenolion I did try this but it does not work if the row exists

Comment: you are using "=" thats why it is returning always true,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most efficient way to find if a row exists or not.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM playerTable WHERE playerNumber="Here comes the player number");
```

It will return 1 if there is a row with playerNumber in the table or will return 0 if there is no row in the table.

Comment: Thank you, will give this a go

Comment: @YassarHaq Give it a try and dont forget to create index on playerTable.playerNumber.

Comment: When you say create index, what do you mean? Can you possibly provide some documentation/example on this, please. Also, tried this and it looks to have worked thanks

Comment: Here is what index and how to create it . http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/

Comment: Dont use the random index commands without reading about them.